# Solr Fields, set 'stored=false' still appearing in query response

Tags: solrcloud

Solr Fields in schema (Solr v6.6), marked as 'stored=false' still appearing in query response

Answer (score 0):

Did we reindex the document after changing the schmea , I hope you are aware for solr cloud we need to do up config. if you are using solr cloud, then do up config of your schema into zookeeper and restart the solr and then try.

Comment: Thanks, all the config related to Solr Cloud and Zookeeper ensemble has been done.. successfully and that's how Solr is up. Issue comes when I index document, regarding all the fields populating even if most of them marked as "stored=false"